# jquery hover missing something

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i need help about jquery hover.

I have created this **[demo](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/jAxzmK)** from codepen.io

In this demo you can see the image. When you hover the image `.blur` div will be displayed. If you dragging the mouse cursor over the image you can see that there is something wrong.It is like flashing lights.

How can I solve this problem. Anyone can help me here ?

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".post").hover(
      function() {
         $(".blur").addClass('active');
      },
      function() {
         $(".blur").removeClass('active');
      }
   );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When the image is shown, you not hovering `.post` anymore, you're hovering the `img` instead. You can change it simple like this:

```
$(".post, .post img")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i want to add zoom effect for post div also. What can i do if i add if for img ?

Comment: Can you make an example for me? Actually this solution could work for this too. So please give me more info then ...

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `<div class="blur">` is outside the `<div class="post">` container and once your mouse is hovering it, it's considered as a `mouseout` state and the `.active` class is being removed, hence the blinking.

Try to move it into the `.post` container:

```
<div class="post">
   <img src="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg">
   <div class="blur"></div>
</div>
```

**Update (as per your comment):**

A better approach would be to use a pseudo `:after` element, as follows:

```
.blurred:after {
   content: '';
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   position: absolute;
   background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.7);
   background-size:cover;
   -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
   -moz-filter: blur(8px);
   -ms-filter: blur(8px);
   -o-filter: blur(8px);
   filter: blur(8px);
   top:0px;
   z-index:1;
}
```

In your JS:

```
$(".post").hover(
   function() { $(this).addClass('blurred'); },
   function() { $(this).removeClass('blurred'); }
);
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="post">
   <img src="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg">
</div>
```

See modified [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyLEbY)

Comment: Hi @haim770 thanks for your answer but if i use blur div in every post that means so many blur div will be come page this is not good. I just want to use one blur div in body. Also blur div should be full screen display.

Comment: `<div class="blur">` is not outside. If you change the blur background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7); you can see.

Comment: thanks for interested to answer my question. But your solution is not really my answer. The blur div should be full screen display.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you hover `.post,` the `.blur` stays above, and it considers you are not hover `.post` anymore. The fix is to put `.blur` inside `.post`.

```
<div class="post">
   <img src="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg">
   <div class="blur"></div>
</div>
```

There is it , your codepen with the modification
http://codepen.io/sandrina-p/pen/mELxrW

Comment: Hi @sandrina-pereira  thanks for your answer but if i use blur div in every post that means so many blur div will be come page this is not good. I just want to use one blur div in body. Also blur div should be full screen display.

Comment: So this is like an effect you want to apply in every "post", right? Let me think about it, give me 5 minutes.

Comment: Okay, so my solution is to not write '.blur' at all on DOM. but instead append the class through jquery with .each() function. The code pen to help you:
http://codepen.io/sandrina-p/pen/mELxrW
If you need further explanation, let me know

Comment: blur div should be full screen display.

Comment: what do you mean my that? the blur should affect all divs in the dom, all the page, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it remove that `white light flickering`, but only when your `mouseleave` `.blur class`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".container").on("mouseenter",function(){
         $(".blur").css("display","block");
     });
     $(".blur").on("mouseleave",function(){
         $(this).css("display","none");
     });
});
```